# Why the Combox.SelectedItem as DataRowView is not casting?

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, datarowview

I have a combox and trying to cast its SelectedItem property to DataRowView like this

```
    DataRowView drFromWareHouse = cmbFromWareHouse.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
```

but it is showing redline and when I move the Cursor on it. It shows me **cmbFromWareHouse** does not exist in the current context. Kindly guide me what's going wrong with it?

Comment: have you checked the name which you are using at code behind is same as UI?

Comment: The variable "cmbFromWareHouse" is out of scope. You can't access it from where you are trying to access it from.

Comment: @DhavalPatel Yes the name is same other properties of cmbFromWareHouse are working

Comment: @JessePetronio yes that was the Prob.. I was Stuck Thanks

Comment: @buddy is it `ComboBox`?

Comment: are you missing runat="server" tag for the ComboBox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable "cmbFromWareHouse" is out of scope. You can't access it from where you are trying to access it from